# Batch Rename Shapfiles in subfolders in R

Tags: r, shapefile, batch-rename

I know this should be something easy, but I'm really struggling with it so figured I'd ask here. I have a group of shapefiles by state for 7 states, and am trying to batch rename them all. Within the "places" folder are state folders entitled the state name ("Iowa","Kansas" etc...). Within each of those folders is a basically gibberish name for the shapefiles ("gz_2010_53_160_00_500k" for the .shp, .prj etc... files). I'd like to rename each of them with the state name so that the shapefile path is basically ("places/Iowa/Iowa.shp" or dbf or prj...). Below was my attempt.

```
setwd("~/Dropbox/places")
files<-list.files(getwd(),pattern="", recursive=T)
sapply(files,function(x) {
    state<-strsplit(x,"/")[[1]][1]#extract state name 
    file_type<-str_sub(files[1],start=-4) #get file type (.shp etc...)
    file.rename(x,paste(state,"/",file_type,sep=""))
})
```

The output of files looks something like this (only first 3 shown):

```
dput(files[1:3])
c("Iowa/gz_2010_19_160_00_500k.dbf", "Iowa/gz_2010_19_160_00_500k.prj", 
"Iowa/gz_2010_19_160_00_500k.shp")
```

When I ran this, each of the filenames spit out in the console and said "TRUE" beneath them. When I looked at the folders, all of the files were gone! Clearly I had done something wrong.

I know this is likely a simple question, but please let me know how I can do this. I really seem to struggle with navigating through directories...

Comment: Can you `dput()` the contents of `files`? Hard to say what's going on when we have no idea what's in those variables.

Comment: It seems like your command `file.rename(x,paste(state,"/",file_type,sep=""))` would rename them to something like `Kansas/.shp`. If you're viewing them through a file browswer, they might not be visible because hidden files start with `.`.

Comment: @MrFlick, edited with a few of them, thanks

Comment: @C.Braun would there be a proper way to name it and replace it within the subfolder?

Comment: @winitheju what about: `file.rename(x,paste(state,"/",state,file_type,sep=""))`?

Comment: @C.Braun I had another mistake in my code that I got from playing around. Where it says "files[1]", it should say "x" that combined with your correction works... Thanks!